# How to use ROC metric with RFE in caret

Tags: r-caret, rfe

How do I use use ROC metric for ref? I've tried this below and I get warning that 'Accuracy' is used intend of ROC.

```
rfFuncs$SummaryFunction <- twoClassSummary
ctrl_rfe <- rfeControl(method = "cv",
                   number = 5,
                   verbose = TRUE,
                   functions = rfFuncs,
                   allowParallel = F)
rf_rfe <- rfe(select(trainData, -target), 
          trainData$target, 
          sizes      = seq(1, ncol(trainData), 100), 
          metric='ROC',
          rfeControl = ctrl_rfe)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rfFuncs` has `summary`, not `SummaryFunction`.

Max